# Selenium C# label text click

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, xpath-1.0

i have this element:

```
<label _ngcontent-c12="" tabindex="0" class="">
    <input _ngcontent-c12="" type="radio" class="ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty">
    <span _ngcontent-c12=""></span> TEST
  </label>
```

and how I can click on it using selenium C#? I try:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//label[text()='TEST']")).Click();
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: your TEST text has space before it or it's a typo? Try label[contains(.,'TEXT')] or label[normalize-space(.)='TEXT']

Comment: *Typo* + *Why is this code not working must include...* Voting to close

Comment: It helps! But:OpenQA.Selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException : element click intercepted: Element <label _ngcontent-c12="" tabindex="0">...</label> is not clickable at point (974, 547). Other element would receive the click: <div _ngcontent-c10="" class="wrapper">...</div>
      (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)

Comment: I think need to click imput, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `ElementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) as solutions:

- *XPath 1*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.XPath("//div[@class='wrapper']")));
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//label[contains(., 'TEST')]//input"))).Click();
  ```
- *XPath 2*:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(By.XPath("//div[@class='wrapper']")));
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//label[normalize-space()='TEST']//input"))).Click();
  ```

Comment: adding WebDriverWait should help!

Comment: Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'WebDriverWait' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) how can fix this?

Comment: @AdrianGielata: Add a `using` directive at the top of your C# file. That is just basic C# and Visual Studio stuff.

Comment: It work but:
element click intercepted: Element <label _ngcontent-c12="" tabindex="0">...</label> is not clickable at point (974, 547). Other element would receive the click: <div _ngcontent-c10="" class="wrapper">...</div>

Comment: @AdrianGielata Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Same message as before

Comment: @AdrianGielata Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: I try this but:
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException : Timed out after 20 seconds

Comment: SendKeys(Keys.Space); not Click() And work! Thanks 4 help!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, its because of missing space before 'TEST'. You may try something like `driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//label[contains(text(),'TEST')]")).Click();` or
`driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//label[contains(.,'TEST')]")).Click();`.

Also, reason maybe in absence of `WebDriverWait`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do more simple:

`driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//label[contains(.,'TEST')]")).Click();`

Answer (score 0):

`driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".ng-untouched.ng-valid.ng-dirty")).Click();`

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am  trying to find particular text that is required to be clicked.

```
    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();  
    var label = driver.FindElements(by.TagName("span")).FirstOrDefault(ele=>ele.Text.Equals("TEST"));
    label.Click();
```

if above solution didn't work, But in Most cases inside Span tag , text are Displayed == false Then we need to use Actions Class.

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveToElement(label).Click().Perform();
```