# How to wait for the disappearance of the Google Loader Icon to continue test execution using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, loader

**My problem:**

I was try crawl Google People Also Ask with selenium and my code write with python, but I have problem when internet slowly. When I click more question, it will show loader icon of Google with this HTML:

```
<g-loading-icon jsname="aZ2wEe" class="nhGGkb S3PB2d" style="height: 24px; width: 24px; display: none;"><img height="24" src="//www.gstatic.com/ui/v1/activityindicator/loading_24.gif" width="24" alt="Đang tải..." role="progressbar" data-atf="0" data-frt="0"></g-loading-icon>
```

Note this: It will show when click more result Google People Also Ask and internet slowly. When load complete g-loading-icon will hiden.

I was test and I think Xpath will change any time with structure of Google result. So I want code to wait until it loading complete to crawl not fail. Because if not waiting it load complete the code will have error: IndexError: string index out of range.

I don't want use time.sleep because I think it not best way.

**Case 1: I was try catch with Xpath. But Xpath will change when structure of result Google change.**

This is my code for case 1:

```
def click_more_gpaa(order):
    # Click button question
    # Condition for check load question
    short_timeout  = 10   # give enough time for the loading element to appear
    long_timeout = 30  # give enough time for loading to finish
    loading_element_xpath = '/html/body/div[7]/div/div[9]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/g-loading-icon'
    loading_element_css_selector = 'nhGGkb.S3PB2d'

    try:

        # Case 1: Test with Xpath
        # wait for loading element to appear
        # - required to prevent prematurely checking if element
        #   has disappeared, before it has had a chance to appear

        is_gppa_show = WebDriverWait(driver, short_timeout).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, loading_element_xpath))
        )

        # then wait for the element to disappear

        is_gppa_show = WebDriverWait(driver, long_timeout).until_not(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, loading_element_xpath)))
        
    except TimeoutException:
        # if timeout exception was raised - it may be safe to 
        # assume loading has finished, however this may not 
        # always be the case, use with caution, otherwise handle
        # appropriately.
        pass
```

**Case 2: I was try catch with CSS Selector. But it not work.**

This is my code for case 2:

```
def click_more_gpaa(order):
    # Click button question
    # Condition for check load question
    short_timeout  = 10   # give enough time for the loading element to appear
    long_timeout = 30  # give enough time for loading to finish
    loading_element_xpath = '/html/body/div[7]/div/div[9]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/g-loading-icon'
    loading_element_css_selector = 'nhGGkb.S3PB2d'

    try:

        # Case 2: Test with CSS_SELECTOR
        # wait for loading element to appear
        # - required to prevent prematurely checking if element
        #   has disappeared, before it has had a chance to appear

        is_gppa_show = WebDriverWait(driver, short_timeout).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, loading_element_xpath))
        )

        # then wait for the element to disappear

        is_gppa_show = WebDriverWait(driver, long_timeout).until_not(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, loading_element_xpath)))        

    except TimeoutException:
        # if timeout exception was raised - it may be safe to 
        # assume loading has finished, however this may not 
        # always be the case, use with caution, otherwise handle
        # appropriately.
        pass
```

Have any way to do that or solution for this?

Or any document and link to read about wait in selenium and python?

I was try research but a lot of document about wait in selenium and python, I was confused about that.

Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 1):

To wait for the *`<g-loading-icon>`* to disappear you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*`invisibility_of_element_located()`*](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.invisibility_of_element_located) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `TAG_NAME`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "g-loading-icon")))
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "g-loading-icon > img[role='progressbar']")))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//g-loading-icon/img[@role='progressbar']")))
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to click on the anchor element when the spinner obscures it using Selenium and Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59658236/how-to-click-on-the-anchor-element-when-the-spinner-obscures-it-using-selenium-a/59659543#59659543)
- [Selenium C# label text click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58010527/selenium-c-sharp-label-text-click/58011048#58011048)
- [Selenium invisibilityOf(element) method throwing NoSuchElementException + WebDriverWait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class) is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51882118/selenium-invisibilityofelement-method-throwing-nosuchelementexception-webdri/51884408#51884408)

Comment: Wow! Thanks you @DebanjanB. Your help very helpful. And very thanks for resource you was sharing!